# Integer conversion in Python

Tags: python

I'm relatively new when it comes to python, and do know how to convert strings to integers. However, for some reason I'm unable to when drawing lines from pygame. Before converting the code to integer, it said I had a deprecation warning and required integers instead of the floats I had. I did what it told me, but now I get an error saying int() can't convert non-string with explicit base.

Before conversion:

```
def draw_board(board):
      pygame.draw.line(screen,WHITE, (WIDTH/3,0),(WIDTH/3,HEIGHT),5)
      pygame.draw.line(screen,WHITE,(WIDTH/1.5,0),(WIDTH/1.5,HEIGHT),5)
      pygame.draw.line(screen,WHITE,(0,HEIGHT/1.5),(WIDTH,HEIGHT/1.5),5)
      pygame.draw.line(screen,WHITE,(0,HEIGHT/3),(WIDTH,HEIGHT/3),5)
```

After conversion:

```
def draw_board(board):
      pygame.draw.line(screen,WHITE, (int (WIDTH/3,0), int (WIDTH/3,HEIGHT)),5)
      pygame.draw.line(screen,WHITE,(int (WIDTH/1.5,0), int (WIDTH/1.5,HEIGHT)),5)
      pygame.draw.line(screen,WHITE,(int (0,HEIGHT/1.5), int (WIDTH,HEIGHT/1.5)),5)
      pygame.draw.line(screen,WHITE,(int (0,HEIGHT/3),int (WIDTH,HEIGHT/3)),5)
```

Comment: Instead of '/', try '//'. The latter is integer division which should get you what you want

Comment: You included two values in one "int" call. Second value is interpreted as base.

Comment: It should be `int(WIDTH/1.5), 0)`

Comment: maybe first convert it - `x1 = int(WIDTH/3) y1 = int(0)` and later use it `line( ..., x1, y1, ...)`. This way code will be more readable and you will see where you made mistake in original code. You do `int (WIDTH/3,0)` but you need `( int(WIDTH/3), int(0) )` or `( int(WIDTH/3), 0 )`

Comment: You're passing too many arguments to `int()`. Try converting each one separately like: `pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, (int(WIDTH/3), 0), (int(WIDTH/3), int(HEIGHT)), 5)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pygame.draw.line(screen,WHITE, (int (WIDTH/3,0), int (WIDTH/3,HEIGHT)),5)
```

There are two problems here.

```
(int (WIDTH/3,0), int (WIDTH/3,HEIGHT))
```

This combines two of your arguments into a tuple - which I'm guessing isn't what you want.

```
int (WIDTH/3,0)
```

This passes two arguments to the int function - which isn't what you want either.

For division between two integers, you may/should have the option of using the "floor division" operator e.g.

```
WIDTH // 3
```

Otherwise, you'll want something more like:

```
pygame.draw.line(screen,WHITE,(0, int(HEIGHT/1.5)), (WIDTH, int(HEIGHT/1.5)),5)
```